# Selenium Webdriver code to find <li> under class

Tags: java, selenium

How can I get the text in a `<li>` with Selenium WebDriver (Java) using the class name, and not with the xpath or css locator.

```
<body><table width="599" align="center" border="0" cellSpacing="0"
       cellPadding="0"><tbody>

<tr>
<td width="599" class="error">
<font color="#ff0000">
<span class="errorHdr">The following errors occurred:</span>
<p></p><ul><ul><li>Invalid or incorrect user name entered.</li>
<li>Incorrect password entered. Passwords are case-sensitive. Please try again.</li>
</ul></ul>
</font>
</td>
</tr>    
</tbody></table></body></html>
```

Comment: Why on earth not using XPath or CSS?

Comment: Using [javascript](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#using-javascript)?

Comment: @stuartd Question is specifically on Selenium WebDriver and not Java script.

Comment: @nilesh the link I posted is to the Selenium WebDriver documentation!

Comment: @stuartd please forgive my ignorance. I just looked at the "javascript" text and didn't bother going to the link :). That said, if one could do something easily using WebDriver then he shouldn't use javascript. It defeats the purpose of `WebDriver`

Answer (score 1):

No you can't get the li text using class name. What is your problem with using xpath or cssSelector? These are made for situation like yours. Anyway just to cater to your whim, there is another way to do it, using tagname, described below:

```
List<WebElement> allLi = driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
for(WebElement eachLi:allLi){
    String tmp = eachLi.getText();
    System.out.println("Text in li: "+tmp); //You may match for your required text, before printing/using it.
}
```

Comment: And if you have tons of `li` in the DOM, it will print all of them. Therefore you need `cssSelector` or `xpath` to filter it down

Comment: Correct, as I mentioned 'just to cater to your whim'. I completely agree cssSelector is best bet in this case, as it is faster than xpath.

Comment: Yeah and the page is **StackOverflow** :D :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the li text without using XPath or CSS selector. Also why are you not willing to use it anyways? I personally prefer CSS over XPath. Below is how I would do it. Essentially I grab all `li` elements under `td` with `classname error`

```
List<WebElement> lis =  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td.error li"));
for(WebElement li:lis){
 System.out.println(li.getText());
}
```